# How to use multiple variable for input with read command?

Tags: bash, variable, read

I am using GNU bash - version 4.2.10(1).
I want to read multiple variables using single **read** command in shell script. So i tried as below:

```
echo " Enter P N R : "
read P N R
```

but it's not working. It just ask for single value of P variable and returns prompt.
I googled it but don't found any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read`, without `-r` expects words on input to be delimited by the characters of the `$IFS` special parameter (by default SPC, TAB and NL, though as `read` reads only one line unless it ends in backslash, NL can't count) where backslash can be used to escape the separator or allow a line to be continued on the next physical line (backslash-newline sequences removed).

So, here the user must enter the values for P, N, R space or tab separated, like:

```
value_for_P value_for_N value_for_R
```

Or if the values can contain space:

```
value\ for\ P value\ for\ N value for R
```

(here we didn't bother escaping the spaces for R as the rest of the line after the third *word* would end-up in R anyway; the user would still need to escape a *trailing* space though).

If you want the user to enter the values on 3 lines, you'd need 3 `read` invocations. You'd then want `-r` to avoid the backslash processing and make IFS empty:

```
IFS= read -r P
IFS= read -r N
IFS= read -r R
```